# Disable the creation of the public folder (C:\\Users\Public) in Windows answer file

Tags: windows, installation, unattended, windows-10, answer-file

I am currently working on a Windows 10 image. One of the things that are important is that no use should be able to save files on the local machine (we use roaming profiles).

The problem is that I don't want manually delete this folder in the post-installation script since I think that might not be enough or might not work as expected (I don't know how this folder actually works).

Is there a way to modify the unattended answer file so this folder/functionality is disabled?